# Need help in understading the counter example

Tags: z3, z3py

Can somebody please explain why I am getting a counter example with this py code.

```
a = Int('a')    
def X(a):
  if (a == 3): 
    return 1
  else:
    return 2

z3.prove( X(a) == If (a == 3, 1, 2) )
```

counterexample
[a = 3]

Answer (score 3):

Your function 'X' will always return '2' for all symbolic variables. That is:

```
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')

def X(a):
  if (a == 3):
    return 1
  else:
    return 2

print X(a)
```

will always print:

```
2
```

This is precisely why Z3 provides the `If` function. Python's 'if' does not work for symbolic values and the tests will simply take the `else` branch.

### Aside:

I'd call this a weakness of the Python interface to Z3, since it's really weakly typed. Ideally, this program should be rejected because of the illegal use of if-then-else, but Python isn't a sufficiently strongly-typed language to give you that level of safety. Bindings to Z3 from other languages would reject the equivalent expression as type incorrect at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So is there any way to add axioms involving functions. Just to give you the context: I need to define axioms over 2 related unnterpreted functions. For example. one function maxcmp(A, B) which returns true is A > B, false otherwise and another function max(A, B) which return the max of A and B. My idea is to define max(A, B) as if(maxcmp(A,B) = True) return A else B, which in turn help me to prove equivalnce in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`X(.)` is a Python function, not a logical or Z3 function. It is evaluated when it is called. This means that the value of `X(a)` in

```
z3.prove( X(a) == If (a == 3, 1, 2) )
```

is determined to be `2` before `z3.prove` is called, because `a` is an `Int('a')` (and not `3`). In this particular case, it's easy to debug such problems by simply printing the Z3 expressions, e.g.

```
print( X(a) == If (a == 3, 1, 2) )
```

reports

```
If(a == 3, 1, 2) == 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So is there any way to add axioms involving functions.  Just to give you the context: I need to define axioms over 2 related unnterpreted functions. 
For example.  one function maxcmp(A, B) which returns true is A >  B, false otherwise and another function  max(A, B) which return the max of A and B.
My idea is to define max(A, B) as if(maxcmp(A,B) = True) return A else B, which in turn help me to  prove equivalnce in this case.

Comment: Yes, use the aptly named `Function(name, sig)` to declare/create uninterpreted function terms: http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#ac526eb9d18decf6dbbe2a64ff844b15d

Comment: Very true, but IMHO `Function` is used to create a declaration, but what I need is some way to define the function, which in z3 world is achieved by 'define-fun', but I need a python-way to do the same.

Comment: @SandeepDasgupta You originally said "uninterpreted functions," and Christoph described precisely how to achieve that. Now you seem to want to actually `define` the function, which is no longer uninterpreted. In any case, this is a sufficiently different topic from the original post. I recommend you post a separate question to detail what you are trying to achieve.